# Laravel move files from one disk to another disk - using `Storage`

Tags: amazon-s3, atomic, laravel-5.6, laravel-filesystem

I have two disks defined in my `filesystems.php` config file:

```
'd1' => [
    'driver' => 'local',
    'root' => storage_path('app/d1'),
],
'd2' => [
   'driver' => 'local',
   'root' => storage_path('app/d2'),
],
```

These disk could also be Amazon S3 buckets, and there could be combination of S3 bucket and a local disk.

Let's say I have a file as `app/d1/myfile.txt` which I want to move to `app/d2/myfile.txt`.

What I'm doing now is

```
$f = 'myfile.txt';
$file = Storage::disk('d1')->get($f);
Storage::disk('d2')->put($f, $file);
```

and leaving the original file on d1 as it doesn't bother me (I periodically delete files from d1).

My questions are:

**Is the** code below atomic, how would I check if it was, and if not how would I make it atomic (for the scenarios when the files are 1GB or something similar in size):

```
$f = 'myfile.txt';
$file = Storage::disk('d1')->get($f);
Storage::disk('d2')->put($f, $file);
Storage::disk('d1')->delete($f);
```

**Is there** a simple way to move files from one disk to another using the `Storage` facade. At the moment I need it to work from one local disk to another but in the future I might need to move them from one S3 bucket to the same one, from one S3 bucket to another one, or from local disk to a S3 bucket.

Thanks

Comment: are you use laravel 5.6? for 5.7 have a new function `Filesystem Read / Write Streams`

Comment: 5.6 but it shouldn't be an issue to upgrade. Thanks for the tip, I'll check it out.

Comment: go to the bottom of the page, https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/releases

Answer (score 6):

I think this way is cleaner and works if you're using remote paths

```
    $directories = ['dir1', 'dir2', 'dir3'];
    $from = 'public';
    $to = 'assets';

    foreach($directories as $directory){
        $files = Storage::disk($from)->allFiles($directory);

        foreach ($files as $file) {

            Storage::disk($to)->writeStream($file, Storage::disk($from)->readStream($file));

            // If you no longer need the originals
            //Storage::disk($from)->delete($file);
        }

        Storage::disk($from)->deleteDirectory($directory);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

The move method may be used to rename or move an existing file to a new location.

```
Storage::move('old/file.jpg', 'new/file.jpg');
```

However, to do this between disks you need to have the full path to the file to move.

```
    // convert to full paths
    $pathSource = Storage::disk($sourceDisk)->getDriver()->getAdapter()->applyPathPrefix($sourceFile);
    $destinationPath = Storage::disk($destDisk)->getDriver()->getAdapter()->applyPathPrefix($destFile);

    // make destination folder
    if (!File::exists(dirname($destinationPath))) {
        File::makeDirectory(dirname($destinationPath), null, true);
    }

    File::move($pathSource, $destinationPath);
```

Comment: You could also `\File::ensureDirectoryExists($destinationPath);`